# Is it preferable to use same structure in conjunctions

Tags: style, redundancy

I wrote:

> It is in the form of a directed tree in which **each node represents** a word and **each directed edge represents** the relation between a word (a head) and one of its dependents.

I tried to use the same verb and structure in the conjunction, is it preferable? or I should use different structure and verbs to avoid repetition of the verb?

something like:

> It is in the form of a directed tree in which each node represents a word and **the edges show** the relations between the words (head) and their dependents.

Comment: *each* won't be correct with 'edges'. You changed your own sentence. If you want to convey 'each', write 'edge' and it's fine.

Comment: As far as I know, The important thing about the coordinator conjunctions (and, or, but) is that the two sides of the conjunction must be in the same form. e.g, two nouns, two adjectives, two sentences, and etc. however, I;v never seen in grammar book or academic text that saying anything about the same verb or structure.

Comment: Moreover, I prefer to use "stands" and "represents" in your sentence

Comment: @MaulikV thank you, but I didn't use "each" with "edges" in the sentence. I asked if I should use two sentences begin with "each" and similar structure to be fluent

Comment: Still not clear. Where did you *begin* two sentences with 'each'? There's only one sentence under 'something like'. And if you are rephrasing the first sentence, 'each' applies to **both** - node and directed edge. In other words, in first it is 'each directed edge' and in second, it becomes 'the edges'. So, is it the edge or edge**s** showing the relation between the words...?

Comment: @MaulikV the second sentence is just an example to rephrase the first sentence, both are my sentences, you can even offer better sentences. It becomes "the edges", "words", "relations" and "dependents" but in fact each edge connect a word with a dependent (I must clear the first sentence)

Comment: The sentence under "something like" is fine, except for the fact that "shows" needs to become "show" to agree with "edges" (your current version has a singular verb and a plural noun) - so it'd be "the edges show".

Comment: I like the repetition of **represents** as in your first example. +1 for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rhetoric (not rhetorical! ;) question more than anything else. Really, it's what's most pleasing to the ear/eye. In this case, I find the parallel structures of the repeated "each" to be more pleasing.

Comment: Thanks, and I liked to hear the opinion of a native speaker!